# Can Jivatma take the position of Lord Rudra?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, bhagavata-purana, creation

Lord Rudra is Human destructive aspect of Supreme Shiva or Sada Shiva.

According to Vaishnav philosophy Lord Vishnu as Maha Vishnu lays in the Causal ocean and breathes out the number of universes. How Vishnu creates and maintains the universes is described in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/questions-about-various-incarnations-of-vishnu/10950#10950).
So when a universe is created, there are 3 personalities that are directly incharge of

1. Maintenance-Lord Vishnu
2. Creation-Lord Brahma
3. Annihilation -Lord Rudra.

Lord Vishnu is Vishnu-Tatva or Sva-amsha(direct expansion) of Maha-Vishnu;i.e. to say Jiva can never become Vishnu in a universe.
Brahma is generally a jiva-tatva(Jivatma; a living entity like us) but sometimes when there is no living entity qualified to take up the position of Brahma, Lord [Vishnu takes up the position of Brahma](http://www.vedabase.com/en/tlc/8).

> If in some kalpa there is no suitable living entity who can act in
>   Brahmā’s capacity, Garbhodaka-śāyī Viṣṇu Himself becomes Brahmā and
>   acts accordingly.

Now as I've said in very 1st statement of this question,**Lord Rudra is Human destructive aspect of Supreme Shiva or Sada Shiva.**
That is, He is Shivatma(Shiv-tatva**).

But here is what Srila Rupa Goswami says in His Laghu-Bhagavatamrit.

> The scriptures explain that, as Brahma' is, so Siva is sometimes a
>   jiva soul and sometimes an amsa-avatara like Lord Sesha.

Here Rupa Goswami gives analogy of Lord Shesha, thats because Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe that Shesha-Nag on whom Lord Vishnu lies is expansion of Vishnu(Vishnu-Tatva); whereas Shesha-Nag who carries universe on His hoods is a separate ; and He could be a Jivatma sometimes.

Now my question is

**Is lord Rudra always an expansion of Shiva(i.e. Sada-Shiva ; just like Anant-Shesha being always an expansion of Lord Vishnu); or can a Jiva become Lord Rudra sometimes in a universe?**

** Shiva-Tatva ,Jiva-tatva, Shakti-tatva, Vishnu-Tatva: These are different types of living entities that I've heard of in Vaishnav terminology.

Comment: As far as i know, there are no stories of Jiva taking position of Rudra in Puranas. Shaiva Puranas say Rudra is Sada Shiva Himself (like Vishnu in Vaishnava Purana) and Vaishnava Puranas say Rudra (they use Shiva) is destructive aspect of Supreme Vishnu.

Comment: Rudra is not human, although he is certainly a manas putra of Bramha. Since he is born in every Manvantara along with other devtas I think qualified jeevatmans can take that position.

Comment: Shiva Purana many times tell 'Those who do (this Puja) become Rudra himself.' But I think this is talking about getting form of Rudra (ie. Sarupya Mukti) and not about Destroyer Rudra... I'm not sure whether Shiva has made some Jeevas as Rudra or not...

Comment: @Yogi yes, he is not human; he is Human destructive aspect as in expansion of Sada-Shiva in material world. According to Skanda Purana, in one Vikalpa Vishnu creates other two trimurtis and in other Vikalpa Shiva creates other two trimurtis (quotting Destroyers comment above from http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/how-does-the-names-and-events-reoccur-in-different-manvantara-or-kalpa-or-differ)

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande nice question. If it is a title then other jeevas could take up ...

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up concepts of vaishnavism and shaivism.  AFAIK SadaShiva is shaivite concept, not vaishnavite concept.  If gaudiya vaishnavism believes that Rudra can sometimes be jivatman then it is their belief.

Comment: @seeker you know any pauranic story or any scriptural reference?

Comment: @Aks you may answer my question from point ofview of any philosophy. All im looking up for is a strong scriptural evidence. Brahma vishnu maheshvar is prety much a universal concept believed by almost all theistic groups i believe.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Shaiva Puranas say Rudra is Sada Shiva Himself ~ No. Rudra is among Trinity where Siva is Parmeshwara beyond everything. We can see it in S.P 7.2. Ch.7 Verse 39 ~ Śaivite Āgama was narrated to Śivā by Śiva. Here siva give knowledge of agama to rudra.

Comment: In S.P 7.1 Ch 8 - title life span of Trinity. We can see siva puran talking about life span of all 3 gods. Here in 24-25. A day of Viṣṇu is the life-time of Brahmā. A day of Rudra is equal to the life-time of Viṣṇu. A day of Śiva is equal to the life-period of one Rudra. A day of Sadāśiva is the life-period of Śiva. A day of Sākṣāt Śivā is the life-period of Sadāśiva. We again say, There are different Śiva.

Comment: Rudra is just a amsha of siva not parmeswar himself. Whereas in dvāita Saivism Trinity including rudra is consider as mere jiva. And paramsiva as Parmeshwara who is beyond everything.

Answer (score 2):

There are several statements in Puranas and other texts where it is stated that the positions of not just Rudra but Vishnu or Brahma too can be attained by a jiva through certain karmas. Of course, Depending on how one chooses to interpret such statements, they can either be taken literally or simply  viewed as Arthavāda (exaggeration).

### Narada Purana III.89.175-176

> **तिथ्यावृत्त्याखिलानिष्टानयन्तादाप्नुयान्नरः ।। षोडशावृत्तितो भूयान्नरः साक्षान्महेश्वरः ।। ८९-१७५ ।। विश्वं स्रष्टुं पालयितुं संहतु
> च क्षमो भवेत् ।। मंडलं मासमात्रं वा यो जपेद्यद्यदाशयः ।। ८९-१७६ ।।**
>
> By repeating these (Thousand Names of Goddess Lalita) sixteen times
> every day, **A Man becomes Mahesvara directly. He will be competent to
> create, Sustain and Annihilate the universe.**

There are similar statements for the other two Trimurtis too in several texts, For example-

### Bhavisya Purana Madhyam parva, part 1, Chapter 10

> **शतरोपी च ब्रह्मत्वं विष्णुत्वं च सहस्रके ।। ५६ ।।**
>
> Growing a hundred saplings of a particular tree leads to Brahma post,
> and growing a thousand saplings leads to Vishnu post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Agni Purana mentions How a Jiva can attain the position of Brahma, Vishnu or Rudra through Tvarita homa. Following which he attains Moksha by attaining Sadasiva Pada.

In the below excerpt the States of Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra are all stated to be attainable by any Jiva just like how one attains the states of plants, animals, reptiles, humans etc.

### Agni Puran Chapter 311

> The fire of the Goddess would glow with the final oblations made with
> the mantra. Then oblation should be made with the principal mantra a
> hundred times and a tenth of that with the subordinate (mantra). Then
> it should be dedicated to the Goddess. Then the disciple should be
> ushered in.
>
> 19-23a. After striking with (the repetition of the mantra of) the
> weapon, the secret subordinate (mantras) should be located in the
> disciple. The disciple should be bound with the subordinate (mantras)
> and then charged with the subordinate (mantras). Then the disciple
> should be made to throw a flower. He is then led to the sacrificial
> pit. One hundred oblations should be made with the principal mantra
> with barley, grains, sesamum and clarified butter. **The first
> oblation (is intended for) the state of a plant, the next one for the
> state of reptiles (like the serpents), and (the subsequent oblations
> are) for the states of being a bird, animal and human beings, mortals,
> Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Rudra.** The concluding oblation would be at the
> end. The disciple would become initiated by a single oblation. (The
> disciple) would have the authority in this way. Listen to me! I shall
> hereafter describe (the way to gain) liberation.

Hindi Translation by Chowkhamba-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a jiva can become Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Indra, Surya anything. Basically, they can get the the Swaroopa Moksha with them before getting Moksha.

Mundaka Upanishad.:

> III-i-1: Two birds that are ever associated and have similar names, cling to the same tree. Of these, one eats the fruit of divergent tastes, and the other looks on without eating.
>
> III-i-2: On the same tree, the individual soul (Jiiva) remains drowned (i.e. stuck), as it were; and so it moans, being worried by its impotence. When it sees thus the other, the adored Lord (Ishwara), and His glory, then it becomes liberated from sorrow.

Srimad Bhagwat Gita 13.23.:

> Within the body also resides the Supreme Lord Maheśhvaraḥ. He is said to be the Witness, the Permitter, the Supporter, Transcendental Enjoyer, the ultimate Controller, and the Paramātmā (Supreme Soul).

Mundaka Upanishad.:

> III-ii-9: Anyone who knows that supreme Brahman becomes Brahman indeed. In his line is not born anyone who does not know Brahman. He overcomes grief, and rises above aberrations; and becoming freed from the knots of the heart, he attains immortality.

Some Puranas, also mentions about becoming these deities.

Sri Shiva Purana 7.2.33.7-8.:

> Brahmā attained his Brahmāhood, Viṣṇu his Viṣṇuhood, Rudra his Rudrahood and Indra his Indrahood. It is by means of this rite that Gaṇeśa attained his Gaṇeśahood. The linga shall be bathed with white sandal water. Therein Śiva find Śivā shall be worshipped with full-blown white lotuses and bowed to.

Skanda Purana/Khanda. 8 (Ambika Khanda), Chapter 21.:

> 13-14. Pleased with Nandi’s devotion, Lord Shiva offers him boons.: Ask whether you want Brahmatva, Vishnutva, Indratva, or something else – Aditya or Rudra.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..